# How can I tag a button on a UITableView section according to its headerLabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want every delete button to be tagged with its associated section's `headerLabel.text`.

This way, when pressing the delete button runs the `deleteButtonPressed` method, the `deleteFromMatchCenter` Parse function will use the section's `headerLabel.text` value as the parameter. I've tried to do it as below, but this doesn't seem to be recognizing the header title properly.

How can I properly associate each delete button with its respective sections header title, and send that over as the parameter?

**MatchCenterViewController.m:**

```
#import "MatchCenterViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MatchCenterViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *matchCenter;
@end

@implementation MatchCenterViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.matchCenter = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle];
    self.matchCenter.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,320,self.view.frame.size.height-100);
    _matchCenter.dataSource = self;
    _matchCenter.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.matchCenter];

    _matchCenterArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.matchCenterArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"MatchCenter"
                       withParameters:@{
                                        @"test": @"Hi",
                                        }
                                block:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {

                                    if (!error) {
                                        _matchCenterArray = result;
                                        [_matchCenter reloadData];

                                        NSLog(@"Result: '%@'", result);
                                    }
                                }];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return _matchCenterArray.count;
}

//the part where i setup sections and the deleting of said sections

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 21.0f;
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 21)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    _searchTerm = [[[[_matchCenterArray  objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"Top 3"] objectAtIndex:3]objectForKey:@"Search Term"];

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 0, 250, 21)];
    headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _searchTerm];
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];


    UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    deleteButton.tag = section;
    deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(300, 2, 17, 17);
    [deleteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [headerView addSubview:deleteButton];
    return headerView;

}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Initialize cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        // if no cell could be dequeued create a new one
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // No cell seperators = clean design
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // title of the item
    cell.textLabel.text = _matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row][@"Title"];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];

    // price of the item
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", _matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row][@"Price"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:127/255.0f blue:31/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    // image of the item
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row][@"Image URL"]]];
    [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];

    return cell;

}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 65;
}


- (void)deleteButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    // Define the sections title
    NSString *sectionName = [self titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];

    // Run delete function with respective section header as parameter
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"deleteFromMatchCenter"
                      withParameters:
                     @{@"searchTerm": sectionName,}
                               block:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {
                                   if (!error) {
                                       NSLog(@"Result: '%@'", result);
                                       [_matchCenter reloadData];
                                   }
                                }];
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
 #pragma mark - Navigation

 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
 // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't linked your `titleForHeaderInSection:` method, but you're trying to pass indexPath.section when you don't have access to your `indexPath`.

Try this

```
UIButton *deleteButton = (UIButton *)sender; 
NSString *sectionName = [self titleForHeaderInSection:deleteButton.tag];
```

or

```
NSString *sectionName = _searchTerm = [[[[_matchCenterArray  objectAtIndex:deleteButton.tag] objectForKey:@"Top 3"] objectAtIndex:3]objectForKey:@"Search Term"];
```

Comment: I added both of those to the `deleteButtonPressed` method, and its giving me an error stating `no visible @interface for MatchCenterViewController declares the selector titleForHeaderInSection`.

Comment: Ah, I was just going based off your code you posted, since you put `[self titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section]`. I assumed you had the method but didn't copy it over. Does `_searchTerm = [[[[_matchCenterArray  objectAtIndex:deleteButton.tag] objectForKey:@"Top 3"] objectAtIndex:3]objectForKey:@"Search Term"];` work?